# pkg-config: PKG_PROG_PKG_CONFIG: command not found

Tags: macos, build, autoconf, kivy, pkg-config

I get the following error

```
./configure: line 11162: PKG_PROG_PKG_CONFIG: command not found
```

when this is code is executed in ([kivy-ios/tools-build-sdlmixer.sh](https://github.com/kivy/kivy-ios/blob/master/tools/build-sdlmixer.sh))

```
if [ ! -f libtremor/tremor/.libs/libvorbisidec.a ]; then
        try cd libtremor/tremor
        echo > asm_arm.h
        CC="$ARM_CC" AR="$ARM_AR" \
        LDFLAGS="$ARM_LDFLAGS" CFLAGS="$ARM_CFLAGS" \
        OGG_CFLAGS="-I../../libogg/include" \
        OGG_LDFLAGS="-L../../libogg/src/.libs" \
        PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR="../../libogg" \
        ACLOCAL_FLAGS="-I $DESTROOT/share/aclocal -I `aclocal --print-ac-dir`" ./autogen.sh \
            --prefix=$DESTROOT \
                --disable-shared \
                --host=arm-apple-darwin \
                --enable-static=yes \
                --enable-shared=no
        try make
        try make install
        try cd ../..
fi
```

My pkg-config application is in my PATH (/usr/local/bin). I've also tried exporting PKG_CONFIG_PATH on my command line to /usr/local/bin/pkg-config and /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig. I've tried exporting LD_LIBRARY_PATH to various paths as well (not sure where it should point to tbh), and that doesn't seem to help either.

I read something about multiple aclocal directories on my system, which could be problematic, but its not clear to me how to resolve that or determine its the issue.

This linux build newbie (on OSX) appreciates any help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When that script calls `autogen.sh`, `aclocal` is failing to find `pkg.m4`, an M4 macro package that comes with `pkg-config` and provides the `PKG_PROG_PKG_CONFIG` macro. Where is `pkg-config` installed, and what directories is `aclocal` searching?

Comment: which pkg-config returns /usr/local/bin/pkg-config.
echo $PKG_PROG_PKG_CONFIG is not set.
find /usr -name "pkg.m4" returns the following:
/usr/local/share/aclocal/pkg.m4
/usr/X11/share/aclocal/pkg.m4. How do I tell which dirs aclocal is searching?

Comment: So I added another -I to my directory containing pkg.m4, that seems to have gotten me around the problem, although I presume this is indicative of a deeper issue.

Comment: You can set the aclocal path by your own `ACLOCAL_PATH=/usr/local/share/aclocal ./autogen.sh`

Answer (score 3):

Had the same issue with linux Alpine for an DockerImage.

Solved it by installing `autoconf`, `automake` and `pkgconf`:

```sh
apk --update add autoconf automake build-base libtool nasm pkgconf
```